# App knows I'm using fake GPS

Tags: apk, gps

I am using an android app, i was using fake gps app to show my location wrong. But now the app understands that I am using fake location app.

I'm using nox player on the computer, the app has its own fake gps feature. That way he doesn't understand. What can I do so that the app doesn't recognize that I'm using a fake location?

Comment: Your IP address often will also tell the app where you are located e.g. in which town.

Comment: Mock location is for testing purpose, not to deceive apps. Any app can figure our if the provided location is fake using [`isFromMockProvider()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#isFromMockProvider()) method. You need to use an Android framework mod like XPrivacyLua to reaaly hide your location.

Comment: @robert The fake location city I entered is the same as my real city. The place I want to fake is a place 10 minutes away from me.

Comment: @Irfan Latif XPrivacyLua telefona kurulan bir uygulama sanırım. Root gerektiriyor mu? Teşekkürler şimdiden

Comment: @HarunUysal hi, this site has [English-only policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13676/241919). Please use English as the main communication language.